# Devise with Rails API - current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am building an API in Rails and using Devise for Authentication. My front-end is an AngularJS app. I am able to log in and create a new session on the Rails end, but as soon as I try to access the **current_user** method in my UsersController it's nil. Am I missing something here?

Appreciate any help. Thanks

SessionsController:

```
 class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :user => current_user
           }
  end......
```

UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create, :show]

  respond_to :json

  def show
    render :json => {:info => "Current User", :user => current_user}, :status => 200
  end....
```

Comment: `current_user` will be nil in your `show` action because in your `before_filter` you are excluding `:show` when authenticating user. remove the `:show` from `except` option to make it work

Comment: Hi, by removing :show, it no longer goes into that method. Server Response: Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#show as JSON
Completed 401 Unauthorized

Comment: is the user logged in ? because if it is not then it won't go there,  it would redirect to login

Comment: Yes the user is logged in. This occurs when I'm requesting the current user information via api call from my angular app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to define `current_user` and run a custom authentication filter in my API to get the information straight from warden. I got the information below from a conglomeration of a few places [here](http://code.dblock.org/grape-api-authentication-w-devise) and [here](http://resistor.io/blog/2013/08/07/mimimal-api-authentication-on-rails/) and **a lot of trial and error** with a debugger.

```
before_filter :api_session_authenticate!

private

def current_user
  warden.user
end

def warden
  env['warden']
end

def api_session_authenticate!
  return not_authorized unless authenticate
end

def authenticate
  warden.athenticated?
end

def not_authenicated
  #render error messages and 401 status
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having the issue though. I even tried to move away from devise and implement my own Sessions, but it is being reset automatically everytime a new call is made to the api

Comment: If you want to do that, then you need to implement an API key that will be checked every time (definitely read [this post](http://resistor.io/blog/2013/08/07/mimimal-api-authentication-on-rails/) on how to implement that). I purposefully did not include that information in my answer because you said you were wanting to stay with Devise for the API.